# Cascade potentiometers

Tags: cascade

I have a DC Drive where the board max speed setting is too high for the process but operators insist on exceeding it. If I put a physical stop in they just remove/break it. I came up with this idea does anyone know if it will work?. I want to cascade 2 potentiometers, having one on the main panel and one buried inside the panel.[image]

Comment: disconnect the left leg of the top pot

Answer (score 1):

it might, but that depends on how the circuit uses it.

Likely you can just put the outer potentiometer (the 'hidden' one) in series with the user-accessible one on the higher voltage end --

[image]

Comment: Thanks, going to try a bench test tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two pots; a resistor in series with the setting pot will limit its range. Of course, you'll need to find the resistor value by experiment.

Comment: Thanks, Issue is I don't know where to limit the speed yet. Long term may do just as you suggest